# Powershell Word Table single row error

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have the following function that I provide 3 arrays as variables

```
$columnHeaders = @('Ticket ID', 'Date Raised', 'Title', 'Status' )
$columnproperties = @('number', 'opened_at', 'short_description', 'state')
$contents
```

$contents has multiple rows of data matching the columns above, however sometimes may only have 1 row. When the $contents only has 1 row the below function errors out and doesnt print the data.

Using ISE I traced the issue to the $contents.count not showing a value, why is this? is there a way to get around it?

```
function TableOutput ($columnHeaders, $columnProperties, $contents){
    # Number of columns
    $columnCount = $columnHeaders.Count


    # Create a new table
    $docTable = $Word.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add($Word.Selection.Range,$contents.Count,$columnCount)

    # Table style
    $doctable.Style = "Adapt Table"


    # Insert the column headers into the table
    for ($col = 0; $col -lt $columnCount; $col++) {
       $cell = $docTable.Cell(1,$col+1).Range
       $cell.Font.Bold=$true
       $cell.InsertAfter($columnHeaders[$col])
    }
    $doctable.Rows.Add() > Null

    # Load the data into the table
    $i = 1
    $j = $contents.Count
    for($row = 2; $row -lt ($contents.Count + 2); $row++){
        if($row -gt 2){
        }
        for ($col = 1; $col -le $columnCount; $col++){
            Write-Progress -Activity "Processing Table Information" -Status "Adding Row entry $i of $j" -PercentComplete (100*$i/$j)
            $cell = $docTable.Cell($row,$col).Range
            $cell.Font.Name="Calibri"
            $cell.Font.Size="10"
            $cell.Font.Bold=$FALSE
            $cell.Text = $contents[$row-2].($columnProperties[$col-1])
        }
        $i++

    }
    $doctable.Columns.AutoFit()
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast $content as an array of strings and see if that doesn't work better for you.

```
function TableOutput ($columnHeaders, $columnProperties, [string[]]$contents){
```

**Edit:** Sorry, my bad, you are passing objects with properties ad descripbed in $columnheaders, so you would need to cast it as an array of objects instead:

```
function TableOutput ($columnHeaders, $columnProperties, [object[]]$contents){
```

Tested on my end, it works fine with 1 object being passed to the function, as well as an array of two objects being passed to the function.

Comment: no that doesnt work, when i do that no data is output to the table, just creates empty rows.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I just looked at the inner workings of your function. You would need to declare it as an `[object[]]` instead since it's an array of objects not strings.